Minimax not returning best moves for tic-tac-toe
This JS minimax code for playing tic-tac-toe isn't finding the best moves, even when there is a win in one move. What is wrong with it?
EDIT: Example of it going wrong: If the board is ["0"," ", " ", "X", "X", " ", " ", " ", " "] (two Xs in the second row) it returns the best move for O as 1, allowing X to win.
/** 
 * Return a list of possible moves on the board. 
 * 
 * @param {string[]} board - The board.
 * @returns {number[]}
 */
function actions(board) {
    const acts = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        if(board[i] == " ") {
            acts.push(i);
        }
    }
    return acts;
}

/** 
 * Return number of occupied squares on the board. 
 * 
 * @param {string[]} board - The board.
 * @returns {number}
 */
function occupied(board) {
    return board.filter((pos) => pos != " ").length;
}

/** 
 * Decide whether the game is over. 
 * 
 * @param {string[]} board - The board.
 * @returns {boolean} - true if there is a winner or all cells are occupied, otherwise false.
 */
export function terminal(board) {
    return getWinner(board) ||  occupied(board) === 9;
}

/** 
 * Calculate the winner, if any. 
 * 
 * @param {string[]} board - The board.
 * @returns {string} - The name of the winner, or null.
 */
export function getWinner(board) {
    const lines = [
        [0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8],
        [0, 3, 6],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [2, 5, 8],
        [0, 4, 8],
        [2, 4, 6]
    ];
    let winner = null;
    for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
        if (board[a] != " " && board[a] == board[b] && board[a] == board[c]) {
            winner = board[a];
            break;
        }
    }
    return winner; 
}

/** 
 * Calculate the value of a board. 
 * 
 * @param {string[]} board - The board.
 * @returns {number} - 1 if the board is won by X, -1 if the board is won by O, otherwise 0.
 */
function utility(board) {
    const w =   getWinner(board);
    if (w == 'X') {
        return 1;
    } else if (w == 'O') {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

/** 
 * Return the board that results from taking a move. 
 * 
 * @param {string[]} board - The board.
 * @returns {string[0]} - The new board.
 */
function result(board, move) {
    const result = board.slice();
    result[move] =  player(board);
    return result;
}

/** 
 * Calculate whose move it is. 
 * 
 * @param {string[]} board - The board.
 * @returns {string} - The name of the next player.
 */
function player(board) {
    return  occupied(board) % 2 == 0 ? 'X' : 'O';
}

/** 
 * Implementation of the Minimax algorithm. 
 * 
 * @param {string[]} board - The board.
 * @param {boolean} xIsNext - true if X is next.
 * @returns {number} - The best move to take for the current player.
 */
export function minimax(board, isMaximizingPlayer) {
    if (terminal(board)) {
      return [utility(board), null]; // Return utility and null move for terminal states
    }
  
    let bestValue = isMaximizingPlayer ? -Infinity : Infinity;
    let bestMove = null;
  
    actions(board).forEach((move) => {
      let newBoard = result(board, move);
      let [value, _] = minimax(newBoard, !isMaximizingPlayer);
  
      if (isMaximizingPlayer) {
        if (value > bestValue) {
          bestValue = value;
          bestMove = move;
        }
      } else {
        if (value < bestValue) {
          bestValue = value;
          bestMove = move;
        }
      }
    });
  
    return [bestValue, bestMove];
  }


Please provide an example of a board position where the minmax function fails to pick the winning move.

For what it's worth, I had it play against itself from an empty board and from a few different starting configurations, and I didn't see it make any obvious errors.

That said, it will play moves that might seem odd to a human, because it doesn't try to "hope it's opponent misses something". The algorithm assumes the opponent will play optimally.  E.g., if you have it in a trap where you can win two ways, it may choose to block neither, since the game is lost regardless.

@TimGoodman I edited the question to include an example.

That example works for me, at least with the way I was calling your minimax function.  See my answer below

It seems to work fine to me, at least for the cases I tested. You don't show the how you're calling the functions, so maybe you made some mistake there.
To test, I pasted your code into the F12 Dev Tools of my browser, along with these two functions:
function printBoard(board, turn) {
    console.group(`Turn ${turn}:`); 
    console.log(board.slice(0,3).join(' | '));
    console.log('---------');
    console.log(board.slice(3,6).join(' | '));
    console.log('---------');
    console.log(board.slice(6,9).join(' | '));
    console.groupEnd();
}

function play_yourself(board) {
    var xIsNext = player(board) === 'X';
    var turn = occupied(board) + 1;
    while (!terminal(board)) {
        board = result(board, minimax(board, xIsNext)[1]);
        printBoard(board, turn++);
        xIsNext = !xIsNext;
    }
    const winner = getWinner(board);
    console.log(winner ? `Winner is ${winner}!` : "It's a tie");
}

Then you can test how it plays against itself from any starting board state.
For your example:
starting_board = ["O", " ", " ",
                  "X", "X", " ",
                  " ", " ", " "] ;

play_yourself(starting_board)

Output:
Turn 4:
    O |   |  
    ---------
    X | X | O
    ---------
      |   |  

Turn 5:
    O | X |  
    ---------
    X | X | O
    ---------
      |   |  

Turn 6:
    O | X |  
    ---------
    X | X | O
    ---------
      | O |  

Turn 7:
    O | X | X
    ---------
    X | X | O
    ---------
      | O |  

Turn 8:
    O | X | X
    ---------
    X | X | O
    ---------
    O | O |  

Turn 9:
    O | X | X
    ---------
    X | X | O
    ---------
    O | O | X

It's a tie


Thanks Tim, this is puzzling but very useful! I'm calling this code in a React app and the board is managed state, so I will check there isn't something weird going on there.
